# BS4 Grabbing Text in Between <p> Tags that Follow Pattern

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a site using in python using BS4 that follows this pattern:

```
<p>
Text 1
<br/>
Text 2
<br/>
Text 3
<br/>
Text 4
</p>
```

The code I wrote to do this skips "Text 1" and "Text 4":

```
            for br in scraper.findAll('br'):
                next_s = br.nextSibling
                if not (next_s and isinstance(next_s,NavigableString)):
                    continue
                next2_s = next_s.nextSibling
                if next2_s and isinstance(next2_s,Tag) and next2_s.name == 'br':
                    text = str(next_s).strip()
                    if text:
                        wanted_text = next_s.split('Text ')[1]
```

I understand that the reason why it's not grabbing the first and last text in the p tag is because of my second if statement therefore I'm trying to figure out if there's a different way to parse this.

Once I'm able to grab each "Text 1" string I use regex to parse through each one to grab what I actually need so the desired output from this code would be `next_s = "Text 1"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these kind of tasks you can use `.get_text()` with `separator=` parameter, then split on this separator:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
html_doc = """
<p>
Text 1
<br/>
Text 2
<br/>
Text 3
<br/>
Text 4
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

texts = soup.find("p").get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")  # use separator not included in the text
print(texts)
```

Prints:

```
['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']
```

To get only first text:

```
print(texts[0])
```

Prints:

```
Text 1
```

---

Or: Use `.find_all()` with `text=True`:

```
texts = [t.strip() for t in soup.find("p").find_all(text=True, recursive=False)]
print(texts)
```

Comment: @SD_23 You can also use `.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)`, I added it to my answer.

Comment: This is another way of doing the same thing `texts = [i.strip() for i in soup.find("p").strings]`.